# Child component not updating on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass a value to child component yet the value doesn't not update as the parent component value changes. Here is my work

Child component:

```
class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: this.props.data,
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>{this.state.data}</div>
    )
  }
}


export default Test;
```

Parent js file

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    val: 0,
  }
  this.addVal = this.addVal.bind(this)
}

addVal() {
  let val = this.state.val
  val = val + 1
  console.log(val)
  this.setState({
    val
  })
}
render() {
  return(
    <div>
      <Button onClick={this.addVal}> add </Button>
      <Test data={this.state.val} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

The value gets updated on the parent component however, the child component does not get the updated value. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The `constructor()` only runs once** in the start. When the parent is updated it sends new `props` to the `Test` but it doesnot change `state.data` to `props.data` after the component is rendered first time

You are printing `this.state` variable which is not updated. Instead you should print value from `this.props`

```
render(){
    return(
      <div>{this.props.data}</div>
      )
}
```

If you want to detect the new props you can use [`compnentWillRecieveProps()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops)

```
componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps){
    this.setState({data:nextProps.data})
}
```

Comment: is there a way to update the child state as the parent state is changing

Comment: @toymoy I have edited the post. You can do that using `compnentWillRecieveProps()`

Comment: componentWillRecieveProps is deprecated. Use getDerivedStateFromProps  or componentDidUpdate instead

Answer (score 0):

`state` is unnecessary in the child component. It should be enough to render `this.props.data` since that is what you are passing to the child from the parent.